# Removing a Substring From a Given String In Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to remove `substring` starting from `<!Doctype` in any given string whether it is `"Hello <!Doctype"` or  `"Hi <!Doctype"`. After removal the result would be `"Hello "` and `"Hi "` respectively. I want a generalised function for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex with positive lookahead.

```js
console.log('Hello <!Doctype'.match(/.*(?=<!Doctype)/));
```

Answer (score 0):

use the replace Method
Example
Return a string where "Microsoft" is replaced with "W3Schools":

```
var str = "Hello <!Doctype";
var res = str.replace("<!Doctype", "");
```

The result of res will be:

Hello

Comment: i said starting from <!Doctype ...that means the string could be "Hello <!Doctype html" also..so please provide a generalised formula..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using `String.indexOf` function:

```
function removeDocTypeStr(str) {
    return str.substring(0, str.indexOf("<!Doctype"));
}

console.log(removeDocTypeStr("Hello <!Doctype html"));    // "Hello "
console.log(removeDocTypeStr("Hi <!Doctype"));            // "Hi "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str="Hello ABC <!Doctype ABCDEFG";
var new_str = str.split("<!Doctype")[0];
console.log(new_str);
```

Simply use the split function.